# c scanf_s in visual studio 2017 don't work more than once

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>


const int lung = 41;


void main() {

 char ceva1[lung];
 scanf_s("%[a-zA-Z ]s", ceva1, sizeof(ceva1));
 printf("%s", ceva1);
 scanf_s("%[a-zA-Z ]s", ceva1, sizeof(ceva1));
 printf("%s", ceva1);

 _getch();
}
```

Only the first printf_s work, it just printf twice the text. The single way that i found to work is in c++ with getline but i want to do it in c with scanf preferably.

Comment: What do you enter? What number do you expect `sizeof` to produce?

Comment: [This `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) should be helpful. The `"%["` format does not have a `s` suffix.

Comment: without sizeof the scanf_s doesn't even work

Comment: Or `scanf_s("%[a-zA-Z ]s", ceva1, sizeof(ceva1));` -> `scanf_s("%s", ceva1, sizeof(ceva1));` also works. `"%[a-zA-Z ]s"` is not a valid format string for `scanf_s` neither for `scanf`.

Comment: Well you use a really weird input format without saying the reason why, and it shoots yourself in the foot. As you do not test the return value of any `scanf`, you do not see that the second returned 0, probably because the input stream is left on an unacceptable character like a newline.

Comment: ok so fgets doesn't work anymore.... i have to make a linked list and in that list i have a string variable that i have to read with some sort of scanf... and it just don't work, first fget work well then i have a simple scanf for a number variable and the sescon fget get the value that i put in the scanf...

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `scanf_s("%[a-zA-Z ]s", ceva1, sizeof(ceva1));` the %[...]` is a complete input format specifier.  So the format string is saying that the desired string would be followed by an `s` in the input stream.  (however, that `s`, if present would also be consumed.)  Suggest removing the trailing `s` from the format string.

Comment: Please edit the question adding the exact input you are trying to read.

Comment: @Bob__ edited the whole code , the input could be anything like a name or something .

Comment: scanf* doesn't consume the trailing newline, so the next read with fgets returns an empty string (consuming the newline), and the next scanf would try to read a number, failing.

Comment: George, You still have not yet posted input used as requested by [@dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752708/c-scanf-s-in-visual-studio-2017-dont-work-more-than-once/47756079?noredirect=1#comment82465724_47752708).  This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6365425/george-catalin) describes the input yet it is unclear why the true input you used remains unknown.

Comment: BTW, either you are compiling your code as C++ or a `typedef` is missing before the struct declaration.

Comment: George, the recent edits significantly changes the post.   That is not good SO etiquette.  Rolling back.

Comment: If you need to ask something new, complete this post and ask another question as a new post.  Have that post reference this one and indicate why the questions are different.

Comment: sorry , the input text is just a name. i will quit using any C functions for text input and just use cin.

Comment: regarding: `void main() {`  in C, there are only two(2) valid signatures for the `main()` function  (regardless of what visual studio will allow)  Those two signatures both have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: @user3629249 C allows other valid implementation defined `main()` signatures besides just two potable ones.  §5.1.2.2.1 1

Comment: @chux,  sort of true, can add a third parameter that points to the environment strings.  However, they all have `int` for the return type.  Any other return type will cause (on a valid C compiler) the output of a warning about the invalid return type.

Comment: The C header file: `stdio.h` exposes the `getline()` function.  So no need to resort to C++/  However note this in the MAN page for `getline()`: "Since glibc 2.10:  _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700 Before glibc 2.10: _GNU_SOURCE`

Answer (score 3):

Neither call to `scanf_s("%[a-zA-Z ]s",` consumes the `'\n'` keyed in with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  `'\n'` remains as the next character to be read [@Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752708/c-scanf-s-in-visual-studio-2017-dont-work-more-than-once/47756079#comment82466304_47752708).  So the 2nd call reads nothing.  Had code checked the return value of `scanf_s()`, this may have been deduced.

Instead of `scanf*` and `*getc*`, read a line with `fgets()` [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752708/c-scanf-s-in-visual-studio-2017-dont-work-more-than-once/47756079#comment82466074_47752708), and lop off the potential trailing `'\n'` if desired.

```
if (fgets(ceva1, sizeof ceva1, stdin)) {
  ceva1[strcspn(ceva1,"\n")] = '\0';
  // use ceva1
}
```

Avoid using  `scanf*()` anywhere, even for reading numbers.

```
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  int a,b;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d%d", &a, &b) == 2) {
    // use a, b
  }  
}
```

Comment: i edited my post with different code . Please look at it and tell me why first fget work well but then every fget after it doesn't. How to solve it?

Comment: @GeorgeCatalin The answer advised "Avoid using  scanf*() anywhere, even for reading numbers.".  Your post now does not do that but unfortunately uses both  `fgets()` and `scanf_s()`.  When does `scanf_s("%d", &temp->number)` stop taking input?  With the character after the numeric input.  What character is that?  That character is not consumed and is used by the next input call which is `fgets()`.

Comment: Now i understand why it doesn't work. but i will quit using any C functions for input and just use cin..

Comment: @GeorgeCatalin C, like the tag of this post,  does not have `cin`.

Comment: actually the root problem is the trailing 's' on the format strings.  It has nothing to do with any newline in the input stream

Comment: @user3629249 The trailing `s` is irrelevant, yet misleading.  With `"%[a-zA-Z ]"`, scanning continues until a non-letter/- is encountered.  The  scan looks for a `s`, which of course can not be the non-letter that stopped the prior directive - and so the scan stops.  It is not so much that a `s` is there but is, as you say a lack of newline consumption - somewhere.

Comment: @GeorgeCatalin, the C language does not have `cin` nor `cout` nor `cerr`.  Those operators are only found in C++

Comment: i know that c doesn't have cin or cout but i use c++ now, because i can't make it work in C. The problem occurs when i try to red a string and a int value.

Comment: @GeorgeCatalin `"%[a-zA-Z ]s"` is not useful to read a _line_.  Use `fgets()` to read a _line_ and save as a _string_.  `scanf_s("%d", ...` does not read a _line_ with and integer in it.  It only reads an integer, leaving the rest of the line (even if its only `"\n"`) for the next input function.  It is that  line's remnants  that messes up code's next attempt to "red a string" as it gets the remnants instead.  That Is why the best solution is to read lines with `fgets()` and then parse them, as needed, into integers or whatever.

Comment: @chux can you show me an example of parsing an int with fgets please

Answer (score 0):

this expression:

```
"%[a-zA-Z ]s"
```

should be:

```
"%[a-zA-Z ]"
```

Notice no trailing 's'`.

However, this will stop input at any character that is not alphabetic (like a space, or punctuation or newline or digit. )

If wanting to input everything on a line, use a format string like:

```
"%[^\n]"
```

If you post some sample input, we can be much more specific with our help.

Comment: i want a scanf to input a string variabile like a name('George') and then another scanf to input a int variabile.